# Is it possible to use casserole dish to make no-knead bread?

Tags: baking, bread, cast-iron, pot

I don't own a heavy enamel pot, which seems to be the best for no-knead bread. Is it possible to make good no-knead bread in a glass casserole dish?

Comment: I use the ceramic insert from a crockpot for no-knead bread. I don't think I pre-heat it. It has always come out fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i STRONGLY recommend against it. i can speak from experience that the sudden change in temperature can cause glass baking dishes (particularly when they go from as high of a heat required by no-knead bread to a cool room temp) to shatter and explode! i had a pyrex dish go supernova on me once, sending hot flying glass shards all over the kitchen. how i didn't get hit i'll never know, but it melted holes in our floor and left scorch marks!

more information from Consumer Reports: http://tinyurl.com/33dz9o5

you can pick up some heavy pots suitable for no-knead break baking at thrift stores and garage sales for a song. if you can find a cast-iron dutch oven, even better! i urge you to dig around a bit. the results are really worth it.

Comment: Also most casserole dishes are too flat for the size that the basic no-knead recipe expands to. I have made the recipe in a stainless steel soup pot without any problems, even though I was originally told stainless steel didn't hold heat as well as the recommended containers. I think the keys are 1. a lid, 2. the size (roughly as round and high as you want the bread to be), and 3. WON'T EXPLODE. :)